# Running query dynamically inside snowflake sql stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to run the query which is saved in a field in one table and insert the value of query output into another table.
To simplify the ask I have created dummy tables and try to test the logic.

Table 1

```
create table tsql(id string, q string);
insert into tsql values (1,'Select current_date');
```

Table tsql has select query in field name q.

Table 2

```
create table tinput(d date);
```

Table 2 will get updated from the value in table 1.

Below are the stored procedure I am trying to write. I know this can be done in javascript stored proc but I need to write this in sql as we are following SQL for all other.

Procedure so far.

```
create or replace procedure sqlreadwrite(id string)
returns string 
language sql
as
$$
Declare
select_statement String;

begin 
create or replace temp table tk 
as select q from tsql where id = :id;

--select_statement := 'insert into tinp values (execute immediate 'Select Q from tk')';
execute immediate 'insert into tinp values (execute immediate 'Select Q from tk')';
return 'Success';
end;
$$;
```

Till now it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to call execute immediate twice, you should call it only once. One thing i wee is you have not specified the list of columns in you INSERT statement , it is always better to specify the list of column.

-- untested

```
execute immediate 'insert into tinp values (Select Q from tk)';
```

Comment: I have tried this it has not worked. It gives the below error. For that reason I tried using execute statement twice. ERROR info -> Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 10 at position 0 : SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 25 unexpected 'Select'.

Comment: Hi , just to test out can you please try without using  execute immediate , just a SQL and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way, however I am open to suggestion and better approach.
Below is the query.

```
create or replace procedure sqlread(id string)
returns string
language sql
as
$$
Declare
select_statement String;
res resultset;
value string;
res1 resultset;
v string;
begin 

create or replace temp table tk as select q from tsql where id = :id;
select_statement := 'Select Q from tk';
res := (execute immediate :select_statement);

  let c1 cursor for res;
      for row_variable in c1 do
      value := row_variable.Q;
      
      res1 := (execute immediate :value);
      let c1 cursor for res1;
      for row_variable1 in c1 do
            v := row_variable1.current_date::date;
            insert into tinp values (:v);
       end for;
   End For; 
return v;
end;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the target table (tinput) will only accept dates, I wonder what kind of queries are stored in the source table (tsql)? Anyway, I assume there is a business requirement behind this, so your approach should be OK.

Some improvements:

- You may remove the TEMP table as it doesn't provide any benefits.
- If your procedure will only run 1 query from tinput (if IDs are unique), then you don't need a loop.

Here is the sample code:

```
create or replace procedure sqlread(p_id string)
returns string
language sql
as
$$
Declare
select_statement String;
res resultset;
value string;
res1 resultset;
v string;
begin 

    select_statement := 'select q from tsql where id = ?';
    res := (execute immediate :select_statement using (P_ID));

    let c1 cursor for res;
    open c1;
    fetch c1 into value;

    res1 := (execute immediate :value);
    let c2 cursor for res1;
    open c2;
    fetch c2 into value;

    insert into tinput values (:value);
    return :value;
exception
    when other then
          return 'error';
end;
$$;
```